# React Axios Defaut Header Return an Object after Redirect using browserHistory

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I set `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token');` and check every request I made at the header it always set `authorization:[object Object]`.

I've check my token is not an object (I've tried console.log).

But if I set it manually it works properly

```
    axios.get('ping', {
        headers: {'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')}
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.code == 440) {
                return this.props.refreshToken();
            }
        });
```

Any solution?

---

Found the culprit:

When I login, I using `browserHistory.push` when login successful to navigate to dashboard.
After I change to use `window.location.assign('/')` now my header retrieve authorization properly.

Any solution if I want to keep using react router?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a hard-coded string literal, instead of `localStorage.getItem()` call? Like `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'someval'`. EDITED: Another thing is to see if something is changing the Authorization default, in-between setting the default and calling the `axios.get`

Comment: @Leone yes and it return properly. but when I set like my code above it become an [object Object]

Comment: @Leone I've update my question with the culprit. any solution if I want to use react router instead of `window.location`?

Comment: Is `browserHistory.push` somehow changing your localStorage `'token'` item?

Comment: @Leone no it not change anything, but after login the authorization is become object, when i navigate using window.location it set it up properly

Comment: I think I may need to see more of your code. Specially, if there are `onEnter` or `onChange` hooks to your `<Route>`. I tried to simply replicate what your code does in the browser console, and I had no issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129499/discussion-between-leone-and-ssuhat).

Comment: @StefenSuhat Hi im facing the same issue. but i couldnt resolve it by your method. in my case the header looks like authorization:[object Object], eyJ0eX...... How to resolve this?